# Add JavaScript files to the administrative pages

Tags: 7, javascript, theming

How do I add JavaScript/CSS files in every administration pages, using a module?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Using a module, you can follow two methods:

- Implementing [hook_init()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_init/7)
- Implementing [hook_form_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7)

The first method would allow you to add the extra JavaScript (or CSS) files to any administration pages, while the second method would allow you to add those files only to pages containing forms.

```
function mymodule_init() {
  if (arg(0) == 'admin') {
    $path = drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule');
    drupal_add_js($path . '/mymodule.js');
    drupal_add_css($path . '/mymodule.css');
  }
}
```

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if (arg(0) == 'admin') {
    $path = drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule');  
    $form['#attached']['css'][] = $path . '/mymodule.css';
    $form['#attached']['js'][] = $path . '/mymodule.js';
  }
}
```

Replace "mymodule" with the short name of your module; replace "mymodule.js" and "mymodule.css" with the actual names of the JavaScript and CSS files.

[system_init()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.module/function/system_init/7) contains the following code, to add specific files to administrative pages.

```
  $path = drupal_get_path('module', 'system');
  // Add the CSS for this module. These aren't in system.info, because they
  // need to be in the CSS_SYSTEM group rather than the CSS_DEFAULT group.
  drupal_add_css($path . '/system.base.css', array('group' => CSS_SYSTEM, 'every_page' => TRUE));

  // Add the system.admin.css file to the administrative pages.
  if (path_is_admin(current_path())) {
    drupal_add_css($path . '/system.admin.css', array('group' => CSS_SYSTEM));
  }

  drupal_add_css($path . '/system.menus.css', array('group' => CSS_SYSTEM, 'every_page' => TRUE));
  drupal_add_css($path . '/system.messages.css', array('group' => CSS_SYSTEM, 'every_page' => TRUE));
  drupal_add_css($path . '/system.theme.css', array('group' => CSS_SYSTEM, 'every_page' => TRUE));
```

[path_is_admin()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!path.inc/function/path_is_admin/7) is the function that in its documentation is described as:

> Determine whether a path is in the administrative section of the site.

Consider that some node-related paths, such as `node/<nid>/edit`, could be included in the administrative section, depending on the setting found on admin/appearance.

[image: screenshot]

The list of the node paths that could be included in the administrative pages is returned from [node_admin_paths()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_admin_paths/7).

```
  if (variable_get('node_admin_theme')) {
    $paths = array(
      'node/*/edit' => TRUE, 
      'node/*/delete' => TRUE, 
      'node/*/revisions' => TRUE, 
      'node/*/revisions/*/revert' => TRUE, 
      'node/*/revisions/*/delete' => TRUE, 
      'node/add' => TRUE, 
      'node/add/*' => TRUE,
    );
    return $paths;
```

If, for any reason, you need to avoid any page with a path like node/*, you need to add specific code to avoid those, if you are using `path_is_admin()`. Consider that any module could change the pages that are considered part of the administrative pages.

In both the cases, the alternative would be using a library, if the module implements [hooks_library()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_library/7) with code similar to the following one.

```
function mymodule_library() {
  $path = drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule');

  $libraries['mymodule.library'] = array(
    'title' => 'MyModule Library', 
    'version' => '1.0', 
    'js' => array(
      $path . '/mymodule.js' => array(),
    ), 
    'css' => array(
      $path . '/mymodule.css' => array(
        'type' => 'file', 
        'media' => 'screen',
      ),
    ),
  );

  return $libraries;
}
```

In this case, the previous implementation of `hook_form_alter()` would become the following.

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if (arg(0) == 'admin') {
    $form['#attached']['library'][] = array('mymodule', 'mymodule.library');
  }
}
```

Instead of calling `drupal_add_js()`, and `drupal_add_css()`, the code should call `drupal_add_library('mymodule', 'mymodule.library')`.

The pro of using `hook_library()` is:

- Dependencies between libraries are automatically handled. That is what happens in the case of system_library(), which defines two libraries using the following definitions.

  ```
    // Drupal's form library.
    $libraries['drupal.form'] = array(
      'title' => 'Drupal form library', 
      'version' => VERSION, 
      'js' => array(
        'misc/form.js' => array(
          'group' => JS_LIBRARY,
          'weight' => 1,
        ),
      ),
    );

    // Drupal's collapsible fieldset.
    $libraries['drupal.collapse'] = array(
      'title' => 'Drupal collapsible fieldset', 
      'version' => VERSION, 
      'js' => array(
        'misc/collapse.js' => array('group' => JS_DEFAULT),
      ), 
      'dependencies' => array(
        // collapse.js relies on drupalGetSummary in form.js
        array('system', 'drupal.form'),
      ),
    );
  ```

  Calling `drupal_add_library('system', 'drupal.collapse')`, misc/collapse.js and misc/form.js would both be included.
- The CSS files associated with the library would be automatically loaded together the JavaScript files.
- Whenever the library would use more JavaScript, or CSS files, the code to include the library would not change; it would still be using `$form['#attached']['library'][] = array('mymodule', 'mymodule.library');`, or `drupal_add_library('mymodule', 'mymodule.library')`.

There is no need to use [current_path()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--path.inc/function/current_path/7) when you can use [arg()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--bootstrap.inc/function/arg/7). If the path for the current page is admin/structure/block, then

- `arg(0)` will return `"admin"`
- `arg(1)` will return `"structure"`
- `arg(2)` will return `"block"`

#### Update

`hook_init()` is not used anymore from Drupal 8. The alternative for Drupal 8 is using `hook_form_alter()`, [`hook_page_attachments()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_page_attachments/8), or [`hook_page_attachements_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_page_attachments_alter/8). [`hook_page_build()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_page_build/8) and  [`hook_page_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_page_alter/8) are not anymore used in Drupal 8.
What I said about using a JavaScript library is still true, even if it is suggested to use [`#attached`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/8#attached) to attach a library (or a Javascript file, or a CSS file) to a page. Drupal 8 doesn't allow anymore to attach just JavaScript or CSS files to a page; you need to always attach a library, which a set of JavaScript and CSS files, eventually made of just JavaScript or CSS files.

Comment: What if I want to add on every page if i want drupal access "user_access('access administration pages')" ?

Comment: Replace `arg(0) == 'admin'` with `user_access('access administration pages')`.

Comment: The proper way to check if the current page is an admin page would be the `path_is_admin` function. Some administration pages' paths don't start with 'admin'. For instance, depending on the configuration, the `node/add/<content-type>` pages may be configuration ones.

Comment: Awesome post, super thorough, thanks for really covering this one, very helpful and appreciated.

Comment: Pierre Buyle comment is very very useful!

Answer (score 3):

Here are two approaches to adding JS/CSS to pages.

You can add JavaScript and CSS directly to the template file page.tpl.php, since the template files are PHP files, you can check the URL using [arg()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--bootstrap.inc/function/arg/7) and present accordingly.

Alternatively, and better since it's theme independent, create a module that implements [hook_init()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_init/7), and call [drupal_add_js()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7) or [drupal_add_css()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_add_css/7) based on [current_path()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--path.inc/function/current_path/7).

Something like the following code would work.

```
// Runs on every page load.
function mymodule_init() {
  // Check if current path is under "admin"
  if (substr(current_path(), 0, 5) == 'admin') {
    drupal_add_css('path/to/my/css');
    drupal_add_js('path/to/my/js');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I created a module using the steps described here: 
http://purewebmedia.biz/article/2014/04/23/adding-your-own-css-admin-theme

Copied the module text as desribed on that page:

```
    function mymodule_preprocess_html(&$variables) {
// Add conditional stylesheets for admin pages on admin theme.
  if (arg(0)=="admin") {
    // reference your current admin theme  
    $theme_path = drupal_get_path('theme', 'commerce_kickstart_admin');
    // reference your own stylesheet    
    drupal_add_css(drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule') . '/css/mymodule.css', array('weight' => CSS_THEME));
  }
}
```

However the admin check was faulty when I (as one of the things) wanted to style the submit buttons in all pages as well as the node edit form. Since that path goes to node/edit and not admin the check made me scratch my head for hours.

So I came up with this version to make my simple module called admin_css.

**admin_css.info**

```
name = admin_css
description = Custom css alterations for editor interface
core = 7.x
version = 7.x-1.01
```

**admin_css.module**

```
function admin_css_preprocess_html(&$variables) {
    if (path_is_admin) {
        $theme_path = drupal_get_path('theme', 'seven');
        drupal_add_css(drupal_get_path('module', 'admin_css') . '/css/admin_css.css', array('weight' => 0));
    }
}
```

What is different to the answer here is to check if the path is in the administrative part of the site with [path_is_admin](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21path.inc/function/path_is_admin/7) instead of using **arg**. Using arg caused my css-file not to load on the node-edit and other pages.

Answer (score 1):

It's considered bad practice to add JS and CSS from `hook_init()`. Instead you'ld use [`hook_page_build()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_page_build/7):

```
/**
 * Implements hook_page_build().
 */
function MYMODULE_page_build(&$page) {

  if (path_is_admin(current_path())) {

    drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'MYMODULE') . '/scripts/magic.js');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I just used another method that may appeal to front-end devs. [Subtheme](https://www.drupal.org/node/225125) your preferred admin theme and then add a simple:

`scripts[] = myscripts.js`

to your theme.info file that contains the javascript you need for your admin pages. If you wish, you can add more overrides, since this will inherit your favorite admin theme's resources.