# template.php stop js on admin pages

Tags: 7, theming

I am using the following to put js on my site...

```
drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('theme', 'MYTHEME') . '/js/custom.js');
```

But I have noticed that this is also adding the js to pages like update.php and other admin pages. Is there a if variable I can use to only load the js on customer facing pages?

Ive used `drupal_is_front_page()` before, which is great, is there a `drupal_not_admin_page()` or something like that?

A google search for "drupal is not admin page" isnt getting me anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`path_is_admin()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21path.inc/function/path_is_admin/7):

```
if (!path_is_admin(current_path())) {
  // Do something...
}
```

Or check the theme:

```
if ($GLOBALS['theme'] == 'some_theme') {
  // Do something...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code :

```
function mytheme_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
  // clean script from the admin pages
  if (arg(0) != 'admin' || !(arg(1) == 'add' && arg(2) == 'edit') || arg(0) != 'panels' || arg(0) != 'ctools') {
    drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('theme', 'MYTHEME') . '/js/custom.js');
  }
}
```

Comment: This isn't reliable - you can designate pages to use or not use the admin theme through `hook_admin_paths()`, so you need to check the API (or current theme), not the URL

Comment: Ok then pls have a look. [Click Here](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/6641/add-javascript-files-to-the-administrative-pages?answertab=active#tab-top).