# Can't add js to content creation pages

Tags: 7, javascript

I'm trying to add JS to content create pages using the second function from @kiamlaluno's [answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/6641/add-javascript-files-to-the-administrative-pages#answer-6666)

However, this is not working for me.

I created a module with his folder structure:

`add_js
  add_js.info
  add_js.module
  custom.js`

add_js.info:

```
name = Add JS to admin pages
description = Add js to admin pages
core = 7.x
```

add_js.module:

```
<?php

    function add_js_init() {
      if (arg(0) == 'admin') {
        $path = drupal_get_path('module', 'add_js');
        drupal_add_js($path . '/custom.js');
      }
    }
```

custom.js:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $("html").addClass("hello");
});
```

Also tried [this](https://www.drupal.org/node/1253520#comment-4881588) .module file:

```
<?php

function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  switch ($form_id) {
    case 'my_form':
      $form['#after_build'][] = 'mymodule_after_build';
      break;
  }
}

function mymodule_after_build($form, &$form_state) {
  $path = drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule');
  drupal_add_js ("$path/mymodule.js");
  return $form;
}
```

Although I am pretty inexperienced still, I did remember to enable the module and flush the caches... :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
/**
 *  Implements hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter.
 */
function mymodule_form_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['#attached']['js'][] = drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule') . '/js/custom.js';
}
```

In your case would be:

```
/**
 *  Implements hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter.
 */
function add_js_form_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['#attached']['js'][] = drupal_get_path('module', 'add_js') . '/js/custom.js';
}
```

**Note:** This will add the JS to all of your content types node edit pages.

---

If you need to target a specific content type, all you gotta do is add an if statement, see:

[How can I find the form ID of a form?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/5802/how-can-i-find-the-form-id-of-a-form)

```
/**
*  Implements hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter.
*/
  function add_js_form_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'my_form_id') {
      $form['#attached']['js'][] = drupal_get_path('module', 'add_js') . '/js/custom.js';
    }
  }
```

and I believe you could alternatively do this, put the `my_form_id` directly in the hook:

```
/**
*  Implements hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter.
*/
  function add_js_form_my_form_id_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

      $form['#attached']['js'][] = drupal_get_path('module', 'add_js') . '/js/custom.js';

  }
```

Comment: Perfect! Note: for the `my_form_id` will originally be in `my-form-id` format. All you got to do is change the hyphens into underscores.

Comment: What is the difference between `mymodule_form_node_form_alter` and `mymodule_form_alter`?

Comment: @KimberlyW thanks for asking, I have fixed my implement comment. I actually used [hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter/7.x). So `node_form` being the base. Not to confuse with [hook_form_FORM_ID_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7.x) or [hook_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7.x)

Comment: @KimberlyW all of them basically do the same, the only diff is some of these pass the ID directly in the hook; thus, no need to write an if statement.